# Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml caused by org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 2 of document

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I am not so into Hibernate and I have the following problem trying to follow a tutorial. I am using **Hibernate 4**

So I have a client class named **HelloWorldClient**:

```
public class HelloWorldClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

                Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();

                Message message = new Message( "Hello World with Hibernate & JPA Annotations" );

                session.save(message);    

                session.getTransaction().commit();
                session.close();

    }
}
```

As you can see this class use the **HibernateUtil** to retrieve the Hibernate **Session** object, this one:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {           
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");     
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory( new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings( configuration.getProperties() ).build() );
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

and, as you can see, this class use the **hibernate.cfg.xml** configuration file that is putted into the root of my project, this one:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hello-world</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">myPswd</property>

        <!--SQL dialect -->

        <property name = dialect ">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!--Use Annotation - based mapping metadata -->

        <mapping class="entity.Message" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The problem is that when I perform this application I obtain this error message:

```
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:21)
    at util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:10)
    at client.HelloWorldClient.main(HelloWorldClient.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2165)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2077)
    at util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 2 of document  : Non è consentita una destinazione di istruzione di elaborazione corrispondente a "[xX][mM][lL]". Nested exception: Non è consentita una destinazione di istruzione di elaborazione corrispondente a "[xX][mM][lL]".
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2157)
    ... 4 more
```

It seems that it can't read the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file or something like this.

Why? What am I missing ? How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Please stop tagging Hibernate API questions as JPA API!

Answer (score 0):

The mapping document is not a valid XML. Fix the line 19:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

Other then that it shoud work.

Comment: No I still obtain the same error...my doubt is: I think that the tutorial referer to the Hibernate 3 because it use the hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd and I am using Hibernate 4.3.10 version of the hibernate jar. But I don't know

Comment: The DTD 3.0 is fine - the mapping is a valid hibernate 3 file compatible with version 4.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your mapping file :

1. white line is not allowed on line 2: just remove the empty line. (this is the cause of your current error... very explicit by the way : "Error on line 2 of document")
2. quote is missing when you declare the dialect:

   ```
   <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
   ```